# Install SoapUI via Shell Script on CentOS

Tags: installation, centos, vagrant, soapui

I would like to install SoapUI via shell script through vagrant. I would be happy if there would be a way without puppet (not familiar with it)

What I have till now:

```
# Download SoapUI
echo "Download SoapUI"
cd ~
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-x64-5.4.0.sh
chmod 755 SoapUI-x64-5.4.0.sh

# Install SoapUI 
sh ./SoapUI-x64-5.4.0.sh
```

While installation there is a console wizard coming, default values would be fine for me also licence agreements.

Did someone solve it and is willing to share :-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the `-q` flag (I guess standing for *quiet*) so it will install silently

Comment: sometimes the solutions that easy :-) Thank you very much